# When to get JWT token in ASP.NET Core SPA App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an ASP.NET Core app with React frontend and I'm trying to figure out when and how to get a `JWT token`.

I've already implemented the necessary backend work to produce and return a `JWT` but I'm not exactly sure when and how to get the token after user authentication.

I have a login page that uses social logins. Once social provider authenticates the user, the call comes back to my `Callback()` action method that receives the cookie from social network which is where I do my work to make sure the user is a registered user.

Currently, right at this point, I destroy the social cookie and create my own and do a redirect to the home page where the user simply downloads the `JS` files that include all the frontend React stuff.

Just not sure how to do a redirect while returning a `JWT token` in my `Callback()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your user authenticates with the third-party social network, you should receive an access token. Your callback will need to pass that access token to your api to validate the token, check authorization for your app, and create a JWT token. So, this authentication method should receive an access token and return the JWT token in between your login and first call to the api in your React app. Your login front-end will need to store the JWT somewhere that your React front-end can retrieve it (local storage, session storage, or cookie). If your login and React app aren't on the same domain, then you will need to pass it in the request to the React entry point.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the logic. My question, specifically, about sending the `JWT` token to frontend. My callback method is a regular controller action that does a `Redirect` to the home page i.e. `Home` controller `Index` action where the user downloads the frontend `JS` files. Specifically, how do I send the `JWT` token to user during this redirect? The home page must require authentication which ideally uses the `JWT` token and upon verifying the token is good, renders the page which allows the user to download the frontend `JS` file. Where I'm stuck is this transition.

Comment: If you are doing a redirect on the back end and not the front end, the server will send a 302 and you will need to pass the code in the redirect URL and the front end will need to pull it from there. `this.RedirectToAction("index", "home", new {code=jwtToken}`

Comment: You can just make `return Ok(jwtToken)` after your token generation in backend and in React just read it. Or you can pass it as the paremeter in url.

Comment: @pawel his login is happening in a traditional mvc page and then being redirected via the mvc login page to the entry point of React which will be a HTML response not an api response.